# capifony failed: "sh -c 'mkdir -p /test/ /test/releases /test/shared'"

Tags: php, bash, symfony, capifony, ovh

I want to push my **Symfony 2.8 Project** on my Host. But when I execute

```
 cap deploy:setup
```

I get this error:

```
failed: "sh -c 'mkdir -p /test/ /test/releases /test/shared'" on 
   ftp.cluster003.hosting.ovh.net
```

Do you have any answers for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The target directory (`/test/*`) needs to be writable by the user executing the `cap` command.

you need to create it with `sudo mkdir /test` first.